# angular circular dependency work-around

Tags: angularjs

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/L3eeeh6n/

I'm building an app. This app starts with some static data that I can add to, remove from. The problem I'm having (circular dependency) comes from this initial static data. Here's the scenario:

I have 2 services (fruit, basket). Each fruit can belong to only 1 basket, but each basket can hold many fruits. These two services (below) depend on each other:

```
function fruitService() {}
function basketService() {}
```

the reason they depend on each other is because of the initial static data that I have:

```
function fruitService(basketService) {
  var data = [
   {
     id: 0,
     name: 'apple',
     basket: function() { return basketService.getById(this.refs.basket); },
     refs: {
       basket: 0
     }
   }
  ];
}
```

as you can see, I have a function `basket` that returns a basket item, so that I can dynamically retrieve basket objects from fruit objects.

the basket service is similar:

```
function basketService(fruitService) {
  var data = [
   {
     id: 0,
     name: 'basket1',
     fruits: function() { return fruitService.getByIdList(this.refs.fruits); },
     refs: {
       fruits: [0, ...]
     }
   }
  ];
}
```

same as the fruitService, I have a `fruits` function that can give me fruit objects when I ask for them. I've tried different combinations of ways to try to break apart the actual static data and the service to overcome this circular dependency, but its not happening.

how can I architect this without having this circular dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have one of the services use $injector and do a lookup for the service at runtime

```
var injectedService = $injector.get('servicenamehere');
```

You will  need to add $injector to your service parameters for this to work (just in case there was any question)

Comment: I don't like this answer. Yes it resolves the angular error. But the circular dependency is still there.

Comment: Sometime circular dependencies are necessary.  Since neither of us know the full extent of the problem, neither of us can comment on the appropriateness of the solution.

Comment: its still telling me theres a circular dependency: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/L3eeeh6n/1/

Comment: you had to remove the dependency injected into the function `fruitService(basketService)`

Comment: I did, check out the fiddle link i posted

Comment: updated the fiddle.  You need to call it on demand instead of when the object is created.  The code could be optimized to cache the service the first time you get it, but the fiddle gives the basic idea.

Comment: oh I see. that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 services. I think that one is enough.

```
function basketService() {
  var data = [
   {
     id: 0,
     name: 'apple',
     basketName: 'basket1'
   },
  ];

  var service = {
    getFruitById: getFruitById,
    getBasketById: getBasketById
  };

  function getFruitById(fruitId){
    // return one fruit here
  }

  function getBasketById(basketId){
    // return your basket with a list of fruits
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the code modular and maintainable. I may not have mentioned this in the question but this app will grow. As the number of functions increases, this file will become really big. And what if I need to add more services in the future. This solves the problem, but is not ideal for maintainability

Comment: As far as maintainability is concerned, the fact that you have duplicated data in both services is worse than a unique service. I'll update my answer, keeping 2 services and 1 constant.

Comment: what do you mean duplicated data? theres no duplicated data

Comment: @AbdulAhmad sorry I misread. I though your basket contained a list of fruits ID

Comment: my basket does contain a list of fruit ids, its like a foreign key in a sql table. this way I don't load an actual fruit if i don't need it, just a reference to it. and if I need it, i just call the "fruits" function and it'll return the fruits that are in the basket. its like a relational database

Comment: in a relational database, you do not duplicate foreign keys.

Comment: where am i duplicating a foreign key? bro are you just here to fight or something? or to prove that you're right? this answer is crap by the way because its hard coding basket names into the data. what if I want to change the basket that the fruit belongs to. think about your answers before posting

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be use a constant to store your data.

```
angular.module('yourApp').Constant("fruitAndBasketConstant", {
    baskets : [{
        id : 0,
        fruits : [
            {
               // some info
            },
            {
               // some info
            }
        ]
     }]
});
```

And create a service that will query your constant.

```
angular.module("yourApp").factory("FruitService"["fruitAndBasketConstant", function(fruitAndBasketConstant){

    var service = {
        getFruitById: getFruitById
    };

    return service;


    function getFruitById(fruitId){
        // loop through fruitAndBasketConstant.baskets

        // and return the fruit you want
    }

}]);
```

And do the same for your basketService.